# Hive Serde while loading data into a single column

Tags: hive

I created an external table with below serde properties,

```
    ROW FORMAT SERDE
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'separatorChar' = ',',
    'quoteChar' = '\"')
```

When I try to load the data, the below value to be loaded into a single column is moved to the next columns as below,

**Data to be present in single column**

```
"{""t"":""xxxxxxxxx"",""mi_u"":""anon-xxxxxxxxxxx"",""mi_cid"":""xxxx"",""page_title"":""120 pages: Skip line ruling, 1/2\"" writing space, dotted midline, 1/4\"" black cover. Journals, Paperback | xxxxxxxx""}"
```

Data moved as,

**Column a:**

```
{""t"":""xxxxxxxxx"",""mi_u"":""anon-xxxxxxxxxxx"",""mi_cid"":""xxxx"",""page_title"":""120 pages: Skip line ruling, 1/2"" writing space
```

**Column b:**

```
dotted midline
```

**Column c:**

```
1/4"" black cover. Journals, Paperback | xxxxxxxx""}
```

I want the entire data to be in column a.

Please let me know for how this Serde can be modified to accomadate the data into a single column.

Thanks!.

Comment: Are you trying to load `csv` into the external table?

Comment: yes its a csv.gz file